# leading the right path to "beginners"

Tags: discussion

there are some "beginners" to java ee that are posting questions in SO, and they are using `scriptlets` which is not recommended to use since it is a executed in server side. and it seems that they're posting questions because of homeworks or "just to make it work". should we lead them to the right path to follow the `MVC` pattern? or we let them do their own thing?

Comment: Homework or just making it work is okay as long as the questions are specific and others can benefit from it. Leading somebody to the right path ... requires that this someone wants to be leaded. I recommend soft pushing, i.e. comments pointing out why a certain technique is not recommend and refusal to give answers because of "it's not recommended to do so". Other than that... let them learn their own ways and downvote only if the question itself is bad.

Comment: "The right path" tends to be rather subjective. I think you can advice them if you have strong feelings about it, but don't push it too much, and try to answer the question within the scope OP has set.

Comment: should i say "i recommend you to follow the mvc pattern"? @GolezTrol

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't let it grow into a discussion that overshadows the actual question.